# Rack::Test::Methods setting id when using get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-test

I'm struggling with API methods from Rack::Test. Providing the resource parametets, makes sense for the **post** method, but for **get**, seems, it doesn't.
When I want to fetch the resource with definite **id**, I'm trying to make the request:

```
get "/resources/#{id}", {Accept: Mime::JSON}
```

and it actually works, but it doesn't, if I provide an id as a second argument:

```
get '/resources', id: id, {Accept: Mime::JSON} 
# or
get '/resources', {id: id}, {Accept: Mime::JSON}
# omits the id - just fetches all the resources
```

How do I provide the id as a separate parameter? Embedding it inside a string looks awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seconds parameter identifies the payload of the request. `GET` doesn't have payload, since you can't send any data when you perform a `GET` request.

In a get request, the key/value payload is represented by the query string (plus the URI), therefore the first method is the way to go.

If instead of `GET` you use a different method such as `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` or `PATCH`, then the second parameter represents the payload of the request.

```
patch "/resources/#{id}", { foo: "bar" }.to_json, {Accept: Mime::JSON}
```